# Android webview + progressbar: webview is re-shown before page is changed

Tags: android, webview, progress-bar

I have the following problem with my Android app. I'm using a webview which has a progressbar. It works ok, but the problem is that when the progressbar is set to INVISIBLE again (on progress == 100), the webview hasn't changed pages yet (it does so shortly after reshowing).

In sum, it's this:
1. Webview in view
2. Webview to gone, progressbar to visible
3. Progressbar to gone, webview to visible
4. Webview actually changes the page

My goal is to have 4 happen before 3 (and thus not showing the webview before it has actually changed the page.

How can I do this?

My codes is as follows:

> public class MyActivity extends Activity {    WebView mWebView;
>     ProgressBar pd = null;
>
> ```
> @Override
> public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>   getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
>   requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
>
>     setContentView(R.layout.main);
>     pd = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.web_view_progress_bar);
>     mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
>
>     mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
>     mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
>     mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY); 
>     mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.myurl.com");
>     mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());        
>     mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
>         public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
>            if(progress < 100 && pd.getVisibility() == ProgressBar.GONE){
>                mWebView.setVisibility(WebView.GONE);
>              pd.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
>            }
>            pd.setProgress(progress);
>            if(progress == 100 && mWebView.getVisibility() == WebView.GONE) {
>              pd.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
>              mWebView.setVisibility(WebView.VISIBLE);
>            }
>         }
>     });
> }
>   @Override
>    public void onBackPressed(){                  
>         if(mWebView.canGoBack())            
>            mWebView.goBack(); 
>         else
>            super.onBackPressed();   
>         } 
>    }
>
> class ClassWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
>    @Override
>    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
>       return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
>    } 
> }
> ```

Layout:

> android:orientation="vertical"    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>   android:layout_height="fill_parent">
>
> ```
> <ProgressBar
>     android:id="@+id/web_view_progress_bar"
>     style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_centerInParent="true"
>     android:visibility="gone" >
> </ProgressBar>
>
> <WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:id="@+id/webview"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>     android:visibility="visible">
> </WebView>
> ```